# In Yii2, how do I join a table to itself?

Tags: activerecord, yii2, self-join

I have a page table. Pages can have parents, which are also pages. I want to select all pages with parent_id = NULL and their 'children'. But when I try this

```
public function getPages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Page::className(), ['parent_id' => 'id']);
}
```

I get a get a 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'page' error ... I know how to fix this in Yii1, but I can't figure out to fix it in Yii2.

Answer (score 4):

I have done this for my grades module in which I have parent-child relationship for grades.

Follow this steps:

1. In your model file write this code for self join. We need to alias the table name. Here 'parent' is an alias name.

   ```
   public function getParent() {
       return $this->hasOne(self::classname(), ['id' => 'parent_id'])->
                   from(self::tableName() . ' AS parent');
   }
   ```
2. In your view file write this code

   ```
   [

     'label' => 'Parent Grade',

     'value' => ($model->parent_id != '' || $model->parent_id != 0) ? $model->parent->name : 'Root Grade',

   ],
   ```

Here in my code if the `parent_id` field is not null/zero then it will display the parent grade name otherwise "Root Grade".

Answer (score 3):

You need to alias the table name.

```
 $this->hasMany(Category::className(), ['parent_id' => 'id'])->from(['cat' => 'category']);
```

See discussion [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2687).